# Maven:Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am building my project using Maven. My maven version is apache-maven-3.0.4. I am using Eclipse Luna. When I try to build my project I get the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) on project OrionCommunity: Mark invalid -> [Help 1].

Following is the stack trace when I run mvn clean install `-X`:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:53.295s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 09 20:00:26 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/25M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) on project OrionCommunity: Mark invalid -> [Hel
p 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources)
 on project OrionCommunity: Mark invalid
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Mark invalid
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:306)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Mark invalid
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:300)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
        at java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:485)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:416)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:205)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:181)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1856)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1804)
        at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:114)
        ... 23 more
```

My maven repository is under D:/mavenrepo. I have completely deleted all the jars present in the repo and did a clean install. But I still get this error.

Comment: no pom.xml, no logs (except the tail). it's impossible to help you or reproduce an issue. read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This looks like you are filtering some kind of files which you shouldn't. Make `mvn -X compiler | tee mvn.log` and check the log file for `[DEBUG] filtering`. There you can see which file is being filtered. My assumption is you have missed to add files to the `nonFilteredFileExtension`.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you very much. You were my savior of the day.As suggested by you i ran the command and could see in the log the resources getting filtered. In my pom.xml i had the following piece of code

Comment: <resources>
<resource>
<directory>src/main/resources</directory>
<filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
</resources> After commenting it the build was successful.The resources which are being filtered are not needed for the build. But not sure why the build does not work with that piece of code

Comment: My colleague got the same issue but the problem was with one of the file. Not sure what the problem is. We removed the file which was causing the problem and had the filtering code as is and ran the build.It was successful. I hope the problem is only with that specific file and that to the file was changed 3 months back and there were no recent code changes in it

Comment: @AvinashReddy  You should accept an answer if it worked for you.  I had similar issue, and below top ranked answer helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 71):

With:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
```

Was getting the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:300)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:505)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:416)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:205)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1856)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1804)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:114)
    ... 29 more
```

Then it is gone after adding maven-filtering 1.3:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, either add the dependency or go back to previous version (2.6) if you don't need any of the 2.7 new functionalities

Comment: Upgrading maven-resources-plugin to 3.0.1 also solves the problem.

Comment: @Gili the link is now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-325

Answer (score 14):

remove this work for me:

```
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

I guess it is caused by [this filtering bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1077375)

Comment: filtering might be necessary on some project.. this is not a correct answer, in my opinion

Comment: We had filtering set in our master POM and so couldn't easily remove this. We had moved to 2.7. The better approach was described above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28864641/1279002 and we added a dependency on maven-filtering 1.3

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue too because I was filtering /src/main/resources and forgot I had added a keystore (*.jks) binary to this directory.

Add a "resource" block with exclusions for binary files and your problem may be resolved.

```
<build>
  <finalName>somename</finalName>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>*.jks</exclude>
        <exclude>*.png</exclude>
      </excludes>        
    </resource>
  </resources>
...
```

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is to add **include** tag in order to specify exactly what I want to filter.

It seems the resource plugin has problems going through the whole **src/main/resource** folder, probably due to some specific files inside.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the same issue by referencing the latest maven resource plugin release:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the `targetPath` was not having any value it was blank in the `resources --> resource` for the file `directory` with files that had issue.
I had to update it to `global` as seen in the `Code Sample 2` and re-run build to fix the issue.

**Code Sample 1 (with issue)**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/locale</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath></targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
                <include>*.config</include>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

**Code Sample 2 (fix applied)**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/locale</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <targetPath>global</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
                <include>*.config</include>
                <include>*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

From official documentation

> Warning: Do not filter files with binary content like images! This
>   will most likely result in corrupt output.
>
> If you have both text files and binary files as resources it is
>   recommended to have two separated folders. One folder
>   src/main/resources (default) for the resources which are not filtered
>   and another folder src/main/resources-filtered for the resources which
>   are filtered.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

> Now you can put those files into src/main/resources which should not
>   filtered and the other files into src/main/resources-filtered.
>
> **As already mentioned filtering binary files like images,pdf`s etc.**
>   **could result in corrupted output.** To prevent such problems you can
>   configure file extensions which will not being filtered.

Most certainly, You have in your directory files that cannot be filtered. So you have to specify the extensions that has not be filtered.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error because of character '@' in my resources/application.properties. All I did was replacing the '@' for its unicode value: 
`eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discUser:discPassword\u0040localhost:8082/eureka/` and it worked like charm. I know the '@' is a perfectly valid character in .properties files and the file was in UTF-8 encoding and it makes me question my career till today but it's worth a shot if you delete content of your resource files to see if you can get pass this error.

Comment: This happened to me suddenly when I added an email address to a resource file. Thx for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and did the filtering false like below working for me.
You can try the same...

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment, filtering is sometimes needed in the project, thus not a valid answer imo

Answer (score 1):

in my case, it was a confilict with IntelliJ , I've resolved it by building the project from command line and it worked!

Comment: Sam with my case as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that by changing coding format of ressources files to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

This could be a issue in mvn home path in IntellijIdea IDE. For me it worked out when I set the mvn home directory correctly.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I'm using temurin-11.jdk & Spring-Boot 2.7.5 I opted to go the plugin upgrade route.

My Original error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources 
(default-resources) on project my-app: Mark invalid -> [Help 1]
```

After Upgrading my pom as follows:

I've got this resources bit in my build section:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

And then this is my plugin definition:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <delimiters>
      <delimiter>@</delimiter>
    </delimiters>
    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I got a new error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources 
(default-resources) on project my-app: filtering /Users/me/IntelliJ_Workspace/my-app/my-app/src/main/resources/static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
to /Users/me/IntelliJ_Workspace/my-app/my-app/target/classes/static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
failed with MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

As you can see a .woff file extension contains at least 1 matching delimiter but fails to parse. In my case I don't want filtering on anything but `.properties` & `.yaml` files. After reading the [maven-resources-plugin/resources docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#nonFilteredFileExtensions) I found there's a config nonFilteredFileExtensions where we can exclude file extensions we don't want to filter. So my final plugin config looks like:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <delimiters>
      <delimiter>@</delimiter>
    </delimiters>
    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
 <nonFilteredFileExtensions>jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp,png,svg,ttf,woff,woff2</nonFilteredFileExtensions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```