# Maven plugin "mark invalid" in Eclipse (Mars - 4.5.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a newly created Maven project that I imported into Eclipse. Eclipse is complaining about one of the plugins:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm using the EMBEDDED 3.3.1/1.6.0.20150526-2031 version of Maven inside Eclipse.

Here's the error:

```
Mark invalid (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: Mark invalid
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:300)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:416)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.read(MultiDelimiterInterpolatorFilterReaderLineEnding.java:205)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1856)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1804)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:114)
    ... 34 more
    pom.xml /canvass    line 86 Maven Build Problem
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar problem. There seems to be a problem with the maven-filtering dependency. Upgrading to a more recent version fixes the problem:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.7</version>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The solution was originally posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864641

Comment: where do you live so I can buy a beer !? ;)

Comment: I used to have 2.7 but no maven-filtering dependency. With 2.6 it works without maven-filtering.