# "Mark Invalid" error when reading values from application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp, application.properties

I am learning to use Apache Camel with Spring boot. There is an demo I am working on where I am picking up a file from an FTP location and dropping it to a different location.

The route works when I am using the ftps uri directly in the `from()` method. However when I am trying to store the ftps location in the application.properties file and access it from there, I am getting a **Mark Invalid** error.

**This works:**

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        fromFile();
    }
    public void fromFTP() {
        from("ftps:username@localhost/pickup?password=xxxx&delete=true")
            .to("file:E:/output");
    }
```

**This doesnt:**

*application.properties* file

```
ftps.pickup.location=ftps:username@localhost/pickup?password=xxxx
```

Camel Route

```
  @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            fromFile();
        }
        public void fromFTP() {
            from("{{ftps.pickup.location}}&delete=true")
                .to("file:E:/output");
        }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
C:\Users\pathaks\eclipse-workspace\camel-spring-demo>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building camel-spring-demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ camel-spring-demo --
-
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\pathaks\eclipse-workspace\camel-spring-demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) @ camel-spri
ng-demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.996 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-17T17:56:48Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/123M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2
.7:resources (default-resources) on project camel-spring-demo: Mark invalid -> [
Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pathak</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.17.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31961550/3584153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with Maven filtering. There's a bug in org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources. The error you get is down to the application.properties file being created, not the change in your routebuilder.

The parent 1.5.17.RELEASE of springboot pom brings in maven-resources-plugin 2.7. It has the following to apply filtering to resource files

```
    <!-- Turn on filtering by default for application properties -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application*.yml</include>
                <include>**/application*.yaml</include>
                <include>**/application*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/application*.yml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/application*.yaml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/application*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Use a version of springboot parent with a version of maven-resources-plugin other than 2.7.

e.g.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: This helped! However, I kept the spring-boot-starter parent as it is and added this in the build section

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.7</version>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>