# Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to set up a Dicord-Bot with eclipse and Maven. The Problem is, that I get 2 Errors everytime and nothing seemes to work.

I tried everything from this post: [Maven:Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281322/mavenfailed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources-plugin2-7)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dsdsds</groupId>
  <artifactId>dsdsds</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This are the Error messages:

```
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.1, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.1, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache...
```

and

```
Execution default-testResources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.1, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources:default-testResources:process-test-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-testResources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.1, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.
```

Eclipse shows a Error at the End of this: `xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">`

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah ok I found the solution.

I deleted the .m2 folder in %USERPROFILE% and updated the project.

Comment: Well, that seems to have worked for me too! This oddly just cropped up at one point and then would (very briefly disappear) and then immediately reappear on the next rebuild. It was driving me nutty. So far, seems to be holding steady with a fresh local repo. Cheers!